# How to fix erb tag in Atom from requiring a space to tab-complete?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, atom-editor

Up until about 2 versions of Atom ago, doing `h={tab}` would autocomplete into `h<%= %>`. Obviously this still happens now, however for some reason it is required that the `"="` be after a space. Example:

`hello={tab}`

Does NOT autocomplete to

`hello<%= %>`

Which is the desired syntax. Instead, you have to do

`hello ={tab}` => `hello <%= %>`

and then click/arrow over and delete the space. This is very annoying.
I've gone into the Snippets assuming this was just a typo and the `"="` was accidentally prepended by a space. However as far as I can tell the Snippet is written correctly and this is just a bug? Does anybody know of a way to fix this?

For clarification, most of the other snippets have no issue working up against any character. It seems to only be `={tab}`/`-{tab}`.

Comment: I opened an issue on github about this: https://github.com/atom/language-ruby/issues/103